# Basic Wordpress user cannot see CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, installation, user-account, urls

I have installed CiviCRM on Wordpress and done the setup.
I have created a basic (subscriber role) in WP, have filled the Permissions (Access Control) table for this role, synchronized the WP contacts with CiviCRM. When this user logs into WP, he do not see the CiviCRM menus nor dashboard... 
What is the CiviCRM URL for this user ? I have read the documentation, but nothing about it...
Which configuration is missing ?
Thanks for your help

---

*** Next to my question ***

First of all, I have not designed other roles than the two that are predefined : Administrator and Authenticated. As I understand, I do not need other roles for the moment. My test user has the Subscriber role in Wordpress.
I also have read carefully the documentation.

Next, I have logged in as Administrator in Wordpress&CiviCRM. In the CiviCRM top menu, I go to Administer ->Users and Permissions -> Permissions (Access Control). And there, I enter in WordPress Access Control. I see then an ACL table and I have checked quite all boxes under the Subscriber column.

But nothing changed : a subscriber user does not see the CiviCRM plugin. And the CiviCRM dashboard for this user does not show even if I type "https://mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM (is this the correct url for CiviCRM under Wordpress ?)

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

I'm still stuck with my access privileges problem. Users connected with the "subscriber" role in WordPress do not see the CiviCRM menu in the left WordPress menu.
However, it seems that I have configured correctly the permissions in Administer -> Users & Permissions -> WordPress Access Control.
Any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Have you given them the 'Access civicrm' permission?

Comment: Thank you Aidan, I have given quite all permissions under "WordPress Access Control"  pane. Just to be sure : in this pane, there is no "Access civicrm" permission; but there is a "CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API" permission and I have not given this to a subscriber.

Comment: I've moved the additional info from below into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having tested all the possibilities by checking and unchecking all the options marked in the WordPress Access Control pane, I found that the box 
"CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API" must be be ticked. Otherwise you dont have access to CiviCRM. Strange because it is told to give this to trusted roles only.
The well done documentation is unfortunately lacking on this subject.

Comment: I wouldn't normally recommend giving subscribers this level of access to CiviCRM. What do you want subscribers to be be able to do on your site? You can find the documentation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

Comment: I understand William but it's the only way I found to have the subscribers seeing the CivicCRM interface under WP... The subscriber should be able to do what a "normal user" can do in a NP organisation : create, modify, delete and use contacts.

Comment: I have the same issue. There is no "Access Civicrm" option in the WordPress Access Control screen -- only "CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a role its the first item under "Other Capabilities"

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot see and find what you mean.
Please see here above * Next to my question *.

Answer (score 0):

The URL i have for getting to civicrm under WP is:

https://mysite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM

do you have any plugin that controls visibility of menus by roles?

Comment: Yes but after connection in WP with a subscriber user I get the following error message : 
"No Results Found The page you requested could not be found. ..."
No other plugin that controls visibility by roles

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your details. It definitely helped me solve my very similar issue.
Just as an update, if it can help anyone, I actually enabled the **"CiviCRM: access AJAX API"** permission for the "Subscriber" and "Anonymous User" roles, as I got the error on a public donation payment page where even the non-registered users should have access to.